# Why Qt Creator gives "No absolute path for library" Error for a known library?

Tags: shared-libraries, environment-variables, qt-creator

Hi I am using an industrial machine vision camera (Basler) in a Qt based project. I work under linux Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and Qt 4.8

I have set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and all the required environment variables to find the camera libraries but Still Qt creator gives error when wants to run my application. it gives the following error:

```
 No absolute path for '/opt/GenICam_v2_3/bin/Linux64_x64/GenApi/Generic/libXMLLoader_gcc40_v2_3.so'
```

it is amazing that when I run my Qt project from the Ubuntu terminal it runs without any problem but When I want to run it from the Qt creator it gives the above error message. why Qt creator fails to find the library path ?
This path is not a valid path in my machine and I don't have such a folder "**/opt/GenICam_v2_3**" in my machine, and I don't know why Qt insists on creating such folder.

I used the ldd command for my application and all the libraries was found So I'm sure that nothing is missing.

Is there anything else that I have forget to set before I could run it in Qt Creator ? Why such a phantom location is necessary for Qt Creator ?

I tried to put **my libXMLLoader_gcc40_v2_3.so** which is in another place to the above location but it gives another error message in Qt creator :

```
Environment variable 'GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3' not found
```

I have set this environment variable in /etc/bash.bashrc so I'm sure I've declared it but still Qt Creator cannot find it too.

Content of bash.bashrc

```
export PYLON_ROOT=/opt/pylon4
export GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3=${PYLON_ROOT}/genicam
export GENICAM_CACHE_V2_3=$HOME/genicam_xml_cache
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${PYLON_ROOT}/lib64:${GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3}/bin/Linux64_x64:${GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3}/bin/Linux64_x64/GenApi/Generic:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I copied all the above information to .bashrc in the home directory too.

What should I do to run my application in Qt creator because I need to debug my application and in Ubuntu terminal I cannot do such thing easily.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also trying to make a Basler camera work, and I had the exact same problem as you; except that the same error occured when I build from the terminal. I got the error when I attempt to execute one of the examples after building it.

For me the problem was, that I had only set paths for "GENICAM_ROOT" in .bashrc and not for "GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3" (since only "GENICAM_ROOT" was used by the accompanying makefile). Adding "GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3" solved the problem.

My .bashrc:

```
export PYLON_ROOT=/opt/pylon3  
export GENICAM_ROOT=/opt/pylon3/genicam  
export GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3=/opt/pylon3/genicam  
export GENICAM_CACHE=~/tmp  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${PYLON_ROOT}/lib64  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${GENICAM_ROOT}/bin/Linux64_x64  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${GENICAM_ROOT}/bin/Linux64_x64/GenApi/Generic
```

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: my problem was solved by adding "GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3=/opt/pylon3/genicam " to the build environment window of the qt creator ... but thanks anyway for noticing this